# I need to install MySQL 5.0.9 on a CentOS

Tags: mysql, linux, mysqld, mysql-5.0

I need to install MySQL 5.0.9 on a CentOS. But I'm failing. I realize that the installation is different from MySQL 5.7. Some help?

Comment: on which version of CentOS?

Comment: Why do you need an old version of MySQL?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.